# Youtube library initialization error in youtube search api

Tags: android, youtube-api

i want to implement you tube search API in android, i refereed  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#search_by_keyword but issue is :

```
    private static YouTube youtube;
    youtube = new YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,
                        new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                            public void initialize(HttpRequest request)
                                    throws IOException {
                            }
                        }).setApplicationName("SearchApi")
                        .build();
```

i have an error for above code.
which type of library required for this. i used now `com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;` library.

Answer (score 0):

What error do you get? Write is exactly.

You can find your required libraries in [this link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries)